# Cannot return a subclass when the abstract parent is the return type

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, php-7, discriminator

To avoid defining seperate fields for TestChildEntityA and TestChildEntityB, I defined baseEntities in TestOwnerEntity as their parent which is an abstract class. I know that abstract classes cannot be instantiated neither in PHP 7 nor in any other programming language but this isn't instantiating TestBaseEntity. I initially received the error below when I called getBaseEntities from TestOwnerEntity (getActionAB in the controller) but later realized addBaseEntities and removeBaseEntities can cause the same problem. getBaseEntities works fine if I replace "@var TestBaseEntity[]", in TestOwnerEntity, with either "@var TestChildEntityA[]" or @var TestChildEntityB[]"but that would mean that I have to define two fields instead of just one and also a get method for both which is what I want to avoid.

Error

Notice: Undefined index: owner

```
$this->switchPersisterContext($offset, $limit);
$criteria    = [];
$parameters  = [];
$owningAssoc = $this->class->associationMappings[$assoc['mappedBy']]; // Highlighted
$sourceClass = $this->em->getClassMetadata($assoc['sourceEntity']);
$tableAlias  = $this->getSQLTableAlias($owningAssoc['inherited'] ?? $this- 
>class->name);
```

These are the classes I have in my application:

Base Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"testA" = "TestChildEntityA", "testB" = "TestChildEntityB"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TestBaseEntityRepository")
 */
abstract class TestBaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    abstract public function getOwner(): TestOwnerEntity;

    abstract public function setOwner(TestOwnerEntity $owner): void;
}
```

Child Entity A

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TestChildEntityARepository")
 */
class TestChildEntityA extends TestBaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @var TestOwnerEntity
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TestOwnerEntity", inversedBy="baseEntities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $owner;

    /**
     * @return TestOwnerEntity
     */
    public function getOwner(): TestOwnerEntity
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }

    /**
     * @param TestOwnerEntity $owner
     */
    public function setOwner(TestOwnerEntity $owner): void
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;
    }
}
```

Child Entity B

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TestChildEntityBRepository")
 */
class TestChildEntityB extends TestBaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @var TestOwnerEntity
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TestOwnerEntity", inversedBy="baseEntities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $owner;

    /**
     * @return TestOwnerEntity
     */
    public function getOwner(): TestOwnerEntity
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }

    /**
     * @param TestOwnerEntity $owner
     */
    public function setOwner(TestOwnerEntity $owner): void
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;
    }
}
```

Owning Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TestOwnerEntityRepository")
 */
class TestOwnerEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->baseEntities = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var TestBaseEntity[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *      targetEntity="TestBaseEntity",
     *      mappedBy="owner",
     *      orphanRemoval=true,
     *      cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     */
    private $baseEntities;

    public function getBaseEntities()
    {
        return $this->baseEntities;
    }

    public function addBaseEntities(TestBaseEntity $baseEntity): void
    {
        $baseEntity->setOwner($this);
        if (!$this->baseEntities->contains($baseEntity)) {
            $this->baseEntities->add($baseEntity);
        }
    }

    public function removeBaseEntities(TestBaseEntity $baseEntity): void
    {
        $this->baseEntities->removeElement($baseEntity);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: User
 * Date: 05/02/2019
 * Time: 21:00
 */

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\TestBaseEntity;
use App\Entity\TestChildEntityA;
use App\Entity\TestChildEntityB;
use App\Entity\TestOwnerEntity;
use App\Repository\TestBaseEntityRepository;
use App\Repository\TestChildEntityARepository;
use App\Repository\TestChildEntityBRepository;
use App\Repository\TestOwnerEntityRepository;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $owner = new TestOwnerEntity();
        $objA = new TestChildEntityA();
        $objB = new TestChildEntityB();

        $objA->setOwner($owner);
        $objB->setOwner($owner);

        // Calling addBaseEntities is successful when $owner has been newly instantiated
        $owner->addBaseEntities($objA);
        $owner->addBaseEntities($objB);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($owner);
        $em->persist($objA);
        $em->persist($objB);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response("done");
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/getAB")
     */
    public function getActionAB(TestChildEntityBRepository $repo, TestOwnerEntityRepository $ownerrepo)
    {
        $owner = $ownerrepo->findAll()[0];
        // getBaseEntities fails because baseEntities is defined using an abstract class in TestOwnerEntity
        $b = $owner->getBaseEntities()[0];

        return new Response($b->getId());
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/addA")
     */
    public function addActionA(TestOwnerEntityRepository $ownerrepo)
    {
        $a = new TestChildEntityA();
        $owner = $ownerrepo->findAll()[0];

        $a->setOwner($owner);
        // $owner->addBaseEntities($objA); addBaseEntities fails when $owner is retreived from the database
        // $a->setOwner($owner); setOwner is sufficient to add $a to the database but it's best practice to also
        // append to the entity array in TestOwnerEntity. Removing the check "$this->baseEntities->contains($baseEntity)"
        // in addBaseEntities stops the error.

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($owner);
        $em->persist($a);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response($a->getOwner()->getId());
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/delA")
     */
    public function delActionA(TestOwnerEntityRepository $ownerrepo, TestChildEntityARepository $arepo)
    {
        $owner = $ownerrepo->findAll()[0];

        // removeBaseEntities also fails
        $owner->removeBaseEntities($arepo->findAll()[0]);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->flush();

        return new Response("done");
    }
}
```

If this is not feasible the way I did it, please suggest a better alternative. TestBaseEntity represents a class for the notifications that a user would receive in the application that I'm working on while child A and B are respectively admin notifications and forum notifications that I want to include in the same list because it doesn't make sense that they live in different inboxes.

Edit: I tried using casting but it's not supported natively in PHP.

[MySQL Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/perq2.png)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what issue you're experiencing, can you be a bit more specific in the beginning of your question? Seems there's a lot of info there that doesn't pertain to your question. I've used `DiscriminatorMap` for Addresses, with mappings for Origin, Destination, Selling, Billing, However I used a `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance rather than `JOINED`. Additionally any abstraction in Doctrine, should use `protected` properties rather than `private`.

Comment: @fyrye The code I provided is a side application I wrote to isolate the problem and shorten the relevant code. What I really have is a user class (here TestOwnerEntity) with a method getNotifications (here getBaseEntities). Problem is that a there are two types of notifications: admin and forum notifications (both inherit from abstract calss Notification) which I want to return with the same function getNotifications as opposed to writing getAdminNotifications and getForumNotifications and returning them separately.

Comment: The return type for such a function would be the abstract parent class but it returned the above error "Notice: Undefined index: owner". I can't use SINGLE_TABLE inheritance here since the owner field have the same name "$owner" and is different for each child class (nullable for A / non nullable for B). I wish to know if this possible or if there is a better way to get the same results.

Comment: Right the only qualification for `SINGLE_TABLE` vs `JOINED` is whether the objects all reside in a singe table or different tables. The nullable state is irrelevant and can be handled in your DTO or Entity. So ultimately you're wanting to use a single `getNotifications()` method to retrieve records for a discriminator mapping against multiple tables?  To my knowledge this is not possible, since by default you would have conflicts on the record identifiers. You would need to have a composite primary key or a UUID to circumvent the issue

Comment: Please update your question to show your table schemas. I think you may be going about achieving your desired end-results the wrong way.

Comment: @fyrye I updated my question as suggested. I'd like to add that I'm merely following what I found the developers has suggested through the Symfony demo app. That the owing side of a One-To-Many relationship should have an array that returns all the entries of the owned side (post has an array of comments in the demo app). The catch in my case is that the owned side has subclasses.

Comment: I understand, the other catch is you are using a discriminator mapping to segregate the values into individual objects, but wanting to return them as a single combined value. Based on your table schema, notifications is not abstract, it is an entity as well. So you would have `owner.notifications`, `owner.adminNotifications` and `owner.forumNotifications`.

Comment: @fyrye Sorry for late reply. I'm able to do this in C# by casting the elements first but unfortunately, that's not supported in PHP not to mention it doesn't look like a good practice. Also, yes I forgot to include the type discriminator in the Notification table (all fixed now), though the field does not appear in the corresponding class entity rather set though annotations. That's how MULTIPLE_TABLE inheritance is implemented by doctrine. The base entity being abstract is best practice.

Comment: Where did you come to find that it is is best practice to use abstraction on the [Class Table Inheritance Discriminator](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)? A `MappedSuperClass` typically should be. Keep in mind Doctrine, needs to instantiate objects within Proxies which you will not be able to control. So if you are wanting to retrieve `$user->getNotifications()[0]->getId()`, Doctrine must have a way to instantiate the `Notification` class, which can not be done with class abstraction.